# SQL- Left Join to Replace Not in

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to replace a NOT IN using a LEFT JOIN but for some reason couldn't get the desired result.
Here is the original query

```
create table #versions
(
    Ruleid int, IsDraft INT
)

-- prod #versions
insert into #versions values (1, 0)
insert into #versions values (2, 0) -- this will be deleted

-- Draft version
insert into #versions values (1, 1) -- changed added
```

ORIGINAL CODE (this should give '2'):

```
-- Getting all the rules that are deleted

    select distinct vp.ruleid from #versions vp where vp.IsDraft = 0
    except 
    select distinct vd.ruleid from #versions vd where vd.IsDraft = 1
```

CHANGED CODE:

```
select vp.RuleId from #versions vp 
LEFT JOIN #versions vd 
ON vd.RuleId = vp.RuleId and vp.IsDraft = 0 and vd.IsDraft = 1
```

Am I missing something...??? 
Please advice. 
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you changing the query?  What was wrong with your previous query? Where is the `NOT IN`?  Why do you want to use a `LEFT JOIN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use and ANTI -JOIN you'll need to do two things

1. Test the right side of the join to see if the values are null
2. Don't include filters on the left side in the join

   SELECT vp.ruleid
   FROM   #versions vp
   LEFT JOIN #versions vd
   ON vd.ruleid = vp.ruleid
   AND vd.isdraft = 1
   WHERE  vp.isdraft = 0
   AND vd.ruleid IS NULL

[DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/333232/question-31275312)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why you would want a `LEFT JOIN`. I think a `NOT EXISTS` is more appropriate in this case, assuming I understand what you are trying to do.  You didn't actually specify your desired result, so I'm assuming you want to reproduce the results from your earlier query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT vp.RuleId
FROM #versions vp
WHERE vp.IsDraft = 0
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT null
  FROM #versions vd
  WHERE vd.RuleId = vp.RuleId
  AND vd.IsDraft = 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you @dotjoe for the edit :)  Completely missed that.